# Case When Then from SQL to HQL Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am trying to convert this code from `SQL` to `HQL` hibernate.
Anyone can give a hand?

`CASE WHEN  s.id IS NULL THEN s.direction else l.direction end as street`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-case-expressions):

> **15.33. Searched CASE expressions**
>
> The searched form has the following syntax:
>
> `CASE [ WHEN {test_conditional} THEN {match_result} ]* ELSE {miss_result} END`

```java
List<String> nickNames = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select " +
    "   case " +
    "   when p.nickName is null " +
    "   then " +
    "       case " +
    "       when p.name is null " +
    "       then '<no nick name>' " +
    "       else p.name " +
    "       end" +
    "   else p.nickName " +
    "   end " +
    "from Person p", String.class )
.getResultList();
```

Hibernate provides exactly the same syntax for this expression.